# jQuery form submission without reload (worked at first, but stopped working)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have got this problem, i had this code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#poll_form').ajaxForm(function() { 
        $("#polling_id").load("poll-results.php");  
    }); 
});
```

It has worked perfectly fine, submitted the form, page did not reload and the results were loaded. But now something happened and i can't seem to figure it out. Can you please provide clear code of solution ?

Comment: Based on the plugin I'm assuming you are using: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/, it looks like the code is correct, so we need more details. What goes wrong? When you manually access poll-results.php is it returning the data you want? Is the form even submitting? We need to know what actually is happening to help

Comment: The form action page works fine. When the form is submitted the browser opens the action page showing blank page like it's supposed to (Because all that form does is add records to database)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#poll_form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```